# Win 7 - If 2 pagefiles on separate disks, which does Win 7 use first?

Tags: windows-7, pagefile

For Win 7 Pro - If 2 pagefiles on separate disks are created, say 800MB on OS drive and 16GB (to match system RAM) on SSD, which pagefile will Win 7 use first?  Assume the SSD is faster than the OS drive.

Answer (score 0):

From the TechNet article titled [Learn Best Practices for Optimizing the Virtual Memory Configuration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff382717.aspx):

> **Should you get involved in managing the page file?**
>
> If you have more than one physical disk, moving the page file to a
>   fast drive that doesn’t contain your Windows system files is a good
>   idea. **Using multiple page files split over two or more *physical
>   disks* is an even better idea, because your disk controller can
>   process multiple requests to read or write data concurrently.** But
>   don’t make the mistake of creating two or more page files using
>   multiple volumes on a single physical disk. If, for example, you have
>   a single hard disk that contains volumes C, D, and E, splitting the
>   page file over two or more of these volumes, might actually make your
>   computer run more slowly.

As mentioned, multiple page files, as long as they are located on separate physical disks, can potentially improve the paging speed since the different disk controllers can *simultaneously* handle multiple requests. So it's not a case of which page file Windows will use first (if serial access was involved, there would hardly be any benefit of using multiple page files), but rather that Windows can potentially use both at the same time to boost performance.